# How can I view textures without a material? (Blender 2.8)

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, objects, eevee-render-engine

How do I view textures on my objects without using Materials? I'd prefer not to have to make a material for every object since they don't transfer over to Unity very well. I'd rather just see them all unlit, flat shaded.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I guess it's not possible

Answer (score 1):

Without a material, as far as I know, you can't view a texture.

You can view the texture in Solid Shading mode using Texture as Color without shaders and material output.

This mode uses UV mapping of a mesh directly, no Vector transformations available.

[image: texture in solid shading mode]